# Is there any way to code google conversion api in javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-developer-tools

we can write fb-conversion-api code in node.js using 'facebook-nodejs-business-sdk'. Is there any way to do the same for google-conversion-api

[fb-conversion-api link:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api)
[google-conversion-api:](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/overview)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Question is not clear enough can you share some more data what you are using now